# Wes Bos drum kit project - remove class not working

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm currently coding along this Wes Bos vanilla JS video but I'm having trouble with removing the class part

It adds the class 'playing' like it's suppose to, but when I try to create a function to toggle 'playing' it doesn't work, the transition just sticks

Here's the code so far:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.code}"]`); // attribute selector
const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.code}"]`)
if(!audio) return;
audio.currentTime = 0; 
audio.play();
key.classList.add('playing');
});

function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    e.target.classList.toggle('playing');
  }

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionEnd', removeTransition));
```

```css
.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="KeyA" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="KeyS" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="KeyD" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="KeyF" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="KeyG" class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="KeyH" class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="KeyJ" class="key">
      <kbd>J</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="KeyK" class="key">
      <kbd>K</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="KeyL" class="key">
      <kbd>L</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio data-key="KeyA" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="KeyS" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="KeyD" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="KeyF" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="KeyG" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="KeyH" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="KeyJ" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="KeyK" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="KeyL" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
```

Even inside removeTransition(e), when I write console.log(e) doesn't work
PS: I already corrected keyCode to code

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Where's the HTML?

Comment: apologies! just edited it

Comment: What's the expected behavior? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: By the way `'transitionEnd'` must be `'transitionend'`. Case matters.

Comment: switched to transitionend, still didn't work :(

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What's the expected behavior? Please provide enough information to understand the issue.

Comment: essentially the part i'm struggling with is suppose to make the yellow border around the keys fade after a key is pressed, but once I press let's say A the yellow border sticks

Comment: What I meant is that I corrected to 'transitionend' but still once I press a key the yellow border sticks and it doesn't fade

Comment: Do you want the border to fade after the key is released?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the audio and remove the `playing` class on the [`'keyup'` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event).

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.code}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.code}"]`)
    if (!audio) return;
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    key.classList.add('playing');
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.code}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.code}"]`);
    audio?.pause();
    key?.classList.remove('playing');
});
```

```css
.key{border:.4rem solid #000;border-radius:.5rem;margin:1rem;font-size:1.5rem;padding:1rem .5rem;transition:.07s;width:10rem;text-align:center;color:#fff;background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);text-shadow:0 0 .5rem #000}.playing{transform:scale(1.1);border-color:#ffc600;box-shadow:0 0 1rem #ffc600}kbd{display:block;font-size:4rem}
```

```html
<div class="keys"><div data-key="KeyA" class="key"><kbd>A</kbd><span class="sound">clap</span></div><div data-key="KeyS" class="key"><kbd>S</kbd><span class="sound">hihat</span></div><div data-key="KeyD" class="key"><kbd>D</kbd><span class="sound">kick</span></div><div data-key="KeyF" class="key"><kbd>F</kbd><span class="sound">openhat</span></div><div data-key="KeyG" class="key"><kbd>G</kbd><span class="sound">boom</span></div><div data-key="KeyH" class="key"><kbd>H</kbd><span class="sound">ride</span></div><div data-key="KeyJ" class="key"><kbd>J</kbd><span class="sound">snare</span></div><div data-key="KeyK" class="key"><kbd>K</kbd><span class="sound">tom</span></div><div data-key="KeyL" class="key"><kbd>L</kbd><span class="sound">tink</span></div></div><audio data-key="KeyA" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio><audio data-key="KeyS" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio><audio data-key="KeyD" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio><audio data-key="KeyF" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio><audio data-key="KeyG" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio><audio data-key="KeyH" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio><audio data-key="KeyJ" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio><audio data-key="KeyK" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio><audio data-key="KeyL" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
```

Comment: works perfectly!!! thank you so much! apologies if I wasn't too clear, I'm still fairly new to coding and I gotta learn how to ask questions properly still